# Girsanov Transformation for discrete Random walks

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

currently I am trying to solve the following exercise/idea:

**Setup**:

- Take $\Omega = \{ \omega \, \colon \mathbb{N}_0 \to \mathbb Z \mid \omega(0) = 0 \}$ the state space of all $\mathbb Z$-valued random walks starting at $0$ together with a filtration of $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ given by $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(X_1,\dots,X_n)$.
- Next consider the canocial projection given by $X_n(\omega) = \omega(n)$ and suppose that we are given a family of probability measures $P_p$ with $0 < p < 1$ such that the increments $\xi_n = X_n - X_{n-1}$ are i.i.d. $p$-Rademacher distributed, i.e.
  $$
  P_p(\xi_n = 1) = p \quad \text{ and } P_p(\xi_n = -1) = 1-p.
  $$
  In other words we restrict our case to the case of simple random walks on $\mathbb Z$.

**Question**: Now I want to find an explicit formula for the Radon-Nikodym derivative given by
$$
M_n = \frac{P_{p}\vert_{\mathcal{F}_n}}{P_{1/2}\vert_{\mathcal{F}_n}}
$$
in terms of $n$ and $X_n$. Using this I want to show that $M_n$ is a $P_{1/2}$ martingale with respect to $\mathcal{F}_{\mathbb{N}_0}$.

**My attempt**: Basically since we already know that $P_p$ only assigns positive mass to random walks that are simple it is enough to restrict $\omega \in \Omega$ where the $\xi_k \in \{-1,1\}$ (all the other walks have $0$-probability). Let us start with the easy case:

**Easy case**: Suppose that $X$ is a $1/2$-Rademacher on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P_{1/2})$ and that $Y$ is $p$-Rademacher for $0<p<1$, which Radon-Nikodym derivative can we apply such that we change the law of $X$ to the law of $Y$. Well if one takes $f \colon \{-1,1\} \to [0,\infty)$ given by $f(\omega) = 2p \, \delta_{\omega = 1} + 2(1-p) \, \delta_{\omega = -1}$ where $\delta$ denotes the dirac mass. Then observe that
$$
P_p(X = 1) = \int_{\{1\}} f(\omega) dP_{1/2}(\omega) = p,
$$
and $P_p(X = -1)=1-p$ respectively, thus by definition we know that $f$ is the right Radon-Nikodym derivative.

**Simple Random Walks**: Following the same logic and using that the increments are i.i.d. I believe that the Radon-Nikodym derivative should be given by

$$
M_n = \prod^{n}_{k=1} 2p \delta_{X_k = 1} + 2(1-p) \delta_{X_k=-1}.
$$

Now using the same trick as above we should have

$$
E_{1/2}[M_n \vert \mathcal{F}_{n-1}] = M_{n-1} E_{1/2}[\frac{dP_{p}}{dP_{1/2}}] = M_{n-1} E_p[1] = M_{n-1},
$$
and this finishes the proof however I am not 100% sure if this is correct.